# Can i return list in Mathematica function?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In my code I'm trying to return list of numbers from my function but it gives me just **null**.

```
 sifra[zprava_, klic_] := Module[
  {c, n, e, m, i, z, pocCyklu, slovo},
  pocCyklu = Ceiling[Divide[StringLength[zprava], 5]];
  c = Array[{}, pocCyklu];
  z = Partition[Characters[zprava], 5, 5, 1, {}];
  For[i = 1, i < pocCyklu + 1, i++,
   slovo = StringJoin @ z[[i]];
   m = StringToInteger[slovo];
   n = klic[[1]];
   e = klic[[2]];
   c[[i]] = PowerMod[m, e, n];
  ]
  Return[c]
 ];
 sif = sifra[m, verejny]
```

After the cycles are done there should be 2 numbers in `c`.

`Print[c]` works OK it prints list with 2 elements in it but `sif` is **null**.
`Return[c]` gives me:

> Null Return[{28589400926821874625642026431141504822, 2219822858062194181357669868096}]

Comment: Mathematica requires a different approach than typical procedural languages.  Take a look at some [tutorials](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/12) first.  1. You don't need `Return` to return something from a `Module`, check the documentation examples  2.  A `;` is missing after the `For` 3. No need for `;` after `:=` definition 4. don't pre-initialize an array and use `For` to fill it.  Just use `Table`.  Beginner tip: *never* use `For` as a beginner, as 99% of the time it's not the best solution.  It will really improve your Mma code if you look for other solutions.

Comment: the oddest thing to follow here especially for a traditional programmer -- if you multiply the `Return` "function" by *anything* it has the effect of suppressing the "return" functionality. The lack of a semicolon means you are multiplying the result of the `For` loop ( `Null` ) by the `Return`, hence the odd result which is returned by virtue of being the last statement in the module.

Comment: Thank you very much, the ; after For fixed it(rookie mistake) and thanks for the other suggestions i will definitely look at them.

Answer (score 1):

You could write the function like this:

```
sifra[zprava_, klic_] := Module[{c, n, e, m, i, z, pocCyklu, slovo},
  pocCyklu = Ceiling[Divide[StringLength[zprava], 5]];
  c = ConstantArray[{}, pocCyklu]; 
  z = Partition[Characters[zprava], 5, 5, 1, {}];
  For[i = 1, i < pocCyklu + 1, i++,
   slovo = StringJoin@z[[i]];
   m = ToExpression[slovo];
   {n, e} = klic;
   c[[i]] = PowerMod[m, e, n]];
  c]
```

Demonstrating use with example data:

```
sifra["9385637605763057836503784603456", {124, 2}]
```

> {20, 97, 41, 9, 4, 113, 36}

You could also write the function like this:

```
sifra[zprava_, {n_, e_}] := Module[{z},
  z = Partition[Characters[zprava], 5, 5, 1, {}]; 
  Map[PowerMod[ToExpression[StringJoin[#]], e, n] &, z]]
```